# Not able to enter decimal value in Ionic 2 RC.1 number field

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2 RC.1. I want to have a field which accept dollar amount in it up to 2 decimal places.

```
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Dollar AMount <label class="mandatory-indicator">*</label></ion-label>
        <ion-input type="number" [formControl]="empForm.controls['wsAmtEarned']"  maxlength="30" size="30" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
```

Whenever I enter decimal value (say 5.3) in it, it starts giving me error that the `Nearest possible values are 5 and 6`. How cal I modify it to satisfy my requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, Ionic 2 seems to support [only the following](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/input/Input/) input types, which correspond to HTML5 input types:

> The HTML input type (text, password, email, number, search, tel, or
>   url)

The Number input type in HTML5 defaults to an integer. Actually, a numeric with a default step of `1`. So, you could try to set the `step` attribute on the input (to `step="0.1"`) and see if this is propagated to Ionic.

Otherwise, change the type to `text` and allow your pattern validator to take over.

Comment: Thanks. step="0.01" seems to work fine for a currency edit box.